# In app billing for multiple users in android application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-multiple-users

Is it possible to use google's in app billing mechanism for purchasing subscriptions for multiple user in my application? I have login/register mechanism implemented on my own server and users can purchase subscription to get news. But when i logout and login for another user, i dont have that subscription and have to pay again. I dont think thats possible with IAB android mechanism but i rather ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have a solution for this. Subscription will realy be only simple one-time item that can be purchased and my own server will handle expiration dates.

Comment: I run into similar kind of problem, so subscription is one time for one device no matter how many different user uses the app, am I right?